# executing 2 function without form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am quite new to web development. I want to ask you guys something, so basically i have:

```
<form action="save_file.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="5" maxlength="15">
Id: <input type="text" name="user_id" size="5" maxlength="15">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

and somewhere in the html i also have

```
<button id="btn1">put to txt</button>
```

so basically in my javascirpt i have sth like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $( "#btn1").click(function( ){

        var file_text;

        file_text += $( "#y1f_0" ).text( ) + $( "#separator" ).text( );
        $.post( "save_file.php", {file_data : file_text} , function( data ){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status );
        });
})});
</script>
```

So my question is how to link the form above with btn1? so when I click the btn1, i can also get the value from the form and submit it to save_file.php at the same time, not using 2 function that is clicking the button & submitting the form. Thanks so much for any of your help!!

Comment: put whole code in 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form2 input[name=name]").val();
```

is that what you looking for? You can get elements by name inside a form(actually you canget elements by ID or class etc). but surely you should give ID to form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="save_file.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" size="5" maxlength="15">
    Id: <input type="text" id="user_id" size="5" maxlength="15">
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

I have used ID instead of name.

```
$( "#btn1").click(function( ){
    var Username = document.getElementsById('username').value;
    var Id = document.getElementsById('user_id').value;
    // include the code for saving it to text file. The values of form are stored in the above variables //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id to the form (like "form1") then:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

This will make btn1 send the actual form like if you juste pressed the submit button. No extras needed.